# Error de SQL (1054): Unknown column 'invoice_items.product_id' in 'where clause'uery

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas tardes estimados,
estoy haciendo un desarrollo y hasta el momento todo ha funcionado bien, pero cuando creo un TIGGER con la siguiente condición

```
CREATE TRIGGER `actualizarStockProducto` AFTER INSERT ON `invoice_items`
 FOR EACH ROW UPDATE products SET products.stock = invoice_items.stock_f
   WHERE  products.id = invoice_items.product_id
```

ya me comienza a fallar la inserción de datos en la Tabla invoice_items, si quito el Tigger todo vuelve a funcionar,  lo que  quiero lograr con el tigger es que cuando se inserte un valor en la tabla invoice_items se haga una actualización en el campo stock de la tabla producto, soy nuevo en este proceso de disparador y no si si es que me falta autorizar algo o el campo

agradezco de antemano su apoyo

Comment: Intento pero no me permite subirlo

Comment: De acuerdo a la sintaxis, no puedes usar el nombre de la tabla que dispara el TRIGGER para referirte a sus columnas, debes usar `NEW`  o bien `OLD` según el tipo de TRIGGER y lo que quieras hacer. Para este caso deberás usar `NEW`,  por tanto, debes cambiar esto: `invoice_items.product_id` por esto: **`NEW.product_id`**. Revisa el [MR para más detalles](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html).

Comment: Agradecido  A. Cedano  ya me permitió con la recomendación indicada

Answer (score 0):

En los disparadores no se usa el nombre de la tabla que los lanza para referirse a sus columnas, sino que se usa `NEW` o bien `OLD` según el caso.

Eso viene explicado claramente en el [Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) (la traducción al castellano es mía):

> Within the trigger body, the `OLD` and `NEW` keywords enable you to access
> columns in the rows affected by a trigger. `OLD` and `NEW` are MySQL
> extensions to triggers; they are not case-sensitive.
>
> In an `INSERT` trigger, only `NEW.col_name` can be used; there is no
> old row. In a `DELETE` trigger, only `OLD.col_name` can be used; there
> is no new row. In an `UPDATE` trigger, you can use `OLD.col_name` to
> refer to the columns of a row before it is updated and `NEW.col_name`
> to refer to the columns of the row after it is updated.
>
> ---
>
> Dentro del cuerpo del disparador, las palabras clave `OLD` y `NEW`
> permiten acceder a las columnas de las filas afectadas por un
> disparador. `OLD` y `NEW` son extensiones de MySQL para disparadores;
> no distinguen entre mayúsculas y minúsculas.
>
> En un disparador `INSERT`, solo se puede usar `NEW.col_name`; no hay
> fila antigua. En un disparador `DELETE`, solo se puede usar
> `OLD.col_name`; no hay nueva fila. En un disparador `UPDATE`, puede
> usar `OLD.col_name` para hacer referencia a las columnas de una fila
> antes de que se actualice y `NEW.col_name` para hacer referencia a las
> columnas de la fila después de que se actualice.

Por tanto, tu disparador debe ser escrito así:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `actualizarStockProducto` AFTER INSERT ON `invoice_items`
 FOR EACH ROW UPDATE products SET products.stock = NEW.stock_f
   WHERE  products.id = NEW.product_id
```

Simplemente, en lugar de `invoice_items`, que es la tabla que dispara el código, hemos puesto `NEW`. Así se encontrarán los datos acaban de ser insertados.